# Tkinter canvas doesn't show

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter, Python and Linux. I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 and trying to run my Python-Tkinter code in Atom, but when I run it, only terminal shows up with an information about successful execution and execution time. No canvas appears.

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=200, height=200, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(0,0,100,100)
```

I expect new window with canvas and line to appear, but that doesn't happen, I only get terminal saying:

```
Process returned 0 (0x0)    execution time : 0.307 s
Press [ENTER] to continue...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can add `canvas.mainloop()` to launch the program

Comment: you have to use `mainloop()` to start program - it runs loops which gets events from system, sends to widgets, (re)draws window and widgets, etc.

Comment: @PRMoureu Works just perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like PRMoureu and furas said, I only added `canvas.mainloop()` at the end and that solved my problem! Thank them!

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=200, height=200, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(0,0,100,100)
canvas.mainloop()
```